# Azure Devops required reviewer removable by anyone

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I recently set up a process which will add required reviewers to an azure devops PR. I used an azure function and the devops api because the scenarios which add them were more dynamic than was possible using the branch policies.

The problem I'm having now is that the required reviewers I'm adding in the function have a button to be made optional or removed. The buttons are available to anyone that has the permission `Contribute to Pull Requests`.

The problem is that the same role is required to create PRs. Seemingly that would mean "required" reviewers can be removed by anyone who creates a PR. Is there anyway add required reviewers without using policy and prevent it from being removed/set to optional by every developer in my org?